# How to create files given relative path

Tags: c++, file

I have a path given in command line with a filename in it like:

```
./something.bin infomration /some/some2/thing.txt
```

I know I can put the `/some/some2/thing.txt` into a global variable and use it. Now, I want to:

create a file named thing.txt in the path `/some/some2/`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, you must ask one question per post. If you have 2 questions, make 2 posts. I've edited your post and removed the second question.

Answer (score 2):

For things like this you'll have to use the parameters passed to your main entry point:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // some other code
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `main()` will receive two parameters:

- **argc:** The first parameter will include the number of parameters passed through the second parameter.
- **argv:** The second parameter points to pointers that point to strings with the actual parameters.

The usage is quite trivial, but it's important to remember that the very first "argument" is the executable file itself.

In your example, `argc` would be set to 3 and `argv` would point to the following strings:

- **argv[0]:** `./something.bin` (based on the OS, this could also be an absolute path)
- **argv[1]:** `infomration` [sic]
- **argv[2]:** `/some/some2/thing.txt`

As you can see, all you'll have to do is the following:

- Verify the number of arguments is correct.
- Verify the second argument (`infomration`) is correct.
- Use the third argument to receive the actual file name.

Keep in mind that the user might pass invalid parameters (e.g. invalid characters for a file name) or he might try to trick you into doing something you shouldn't do (like passing reserved names).

Comment: Sorry, but what I want to know is "How to create a file named thing.txt in the path /some/some2/?"